# a POST Ajax call works in Postman but says error 404 in AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api

I have a local API created by ASP.Net, Here is its signature:

```
[ActionName("InsertItemTermData")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public IHttpActionResult InsertItemTermData(long itemID, string ItemModelID, string ItemDescription, string ItemDimensions, string TermsConditions, string PaymentTerms,string Logo)
```

When I run the project and call it from PostMan on its local link:

```
http://localhost:56209/Ecommerce/Item/InsertItemTermData?itemID=484&ItemModelID=Unionair&ItemDescription=air&ItemDimensions=25&TermsConditions=non&PaymentTerms=non&Logo=ffff
```

it works fine and the the breakpoint is hit.

But when I call it via Ajax request, it says Error 404, i.e. that the controller doesn't contain this action.

Here is the Ajax call:

```
var ddTerms = {
    itemID: Rslt,
    ItemModelID: $('#txtBrand').val(),
    ItemDescription: $('#txtBrandDescription').val(),
    ItemDimensions: "None",
    TermsConditions: $('#txtBrandTerms').val(),
    PaymentTerms: $('#txtBrandPaymentTerms').val(),
    Logo: $("#txtLogoPth").val()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: ddTerms,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    url: "Ecommerce/Item/InsertItemTermData",
    success: function (TermsRslt) {
        alert(TermsRslt);
    }
});
```

Note: the variable ddTerms is filled successfully when I add a breakpoint in the Source of the HTML. But the breakpoint in the API isn't hit.

Comment: So I am guessing the path is not correct.... That is what 404 typically means. And you r POSTMAN looks more like a GET than a POST

Comment: try posting following dataToPost instead of ddTerms  `var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(ddTerms); `. also change the url to "~/Ecommerce/Item/InsertItemTermData"

Comment: @Awais Where is `window.ApplicationBasePath` defined? That's not any standard as far as I know.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right, I've had it defined in my code window.ApplicationBasePath = '@Url.Content("~")';

Comment: I thought something like that. :)

Comment: Here is how you should go about debugging these kinds of things. 1) open the browser's developer tools (usually via F12). 2) Go to the network tab. 3) make your request with PostMan. 4) repeat the same steps with jQuery. 5) compare the requests and find out the difference. 6) Think about where the difference comes from & fix it.